# Compare Two values in Javascript then map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dictionary, mapping

I have Different data from different Schema. I want to compare data from both schema to find out if they are same then map through them.

```
allStaff = [
  {
    role: "admin",
    name: "jamal",
    branch: {
      name: "kansas",
    },
  },
  {
    role: "legal",
    name: "keith",
    branch: {
      name: "arizona",
    },
  },
  {
    role: "admin",
    name: "dwyane",
    branch: {
      name: "kansas",
    },
  },
...
];

contributor = {
  fullName: 'Aaraf',
  branch: {
    name: "kansas",
  },
};
```

I want the form option for this contributor to contain only staff in same branch as he is(kansas).

```
<Form.Group controlId="branch">
 <Form.Label>Investment Officer:</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control
    as="select"
    value={investmentOfficer}
      onChange={(e) => setInvestmentOfficer(e.target.value)}
 >
    <option>Investment Officer</option>
     {(allStaff.branch?.name === contributor.branch?.name).map(
       staff) => (
        <option key={staff._id} value={staff._id}>
          {staff.name}
        </option>
                          )
                        )}
                      </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
```

Comment: hi, your code is unclear, have you try to run this? i suggest you to run this first, because this code seems like it will return a bunch of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to filter your data first before you map it so that allStaff is filtered down where the branch names match. I have provided the code to do so below.

```
allStaff.filter((staff) => staff.branch.name === contributor.branch.name)
  .map((filteredStaff) => (
    <option key={staff._id} value={staff._id}>
      {staff.name}
    </option>
));
```

Comment: I've modified. Please take a look

Comment: @pappii3d I have modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks Marty. This worked. Whats your twitter handle? Need to follow

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your code trying to map a boolean... [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is built in attribute for array, also your code not explaining what is you trying to iterate, so the first step **figure out which array you want to iterate** first, after that follow this example,

for this example, im going to assume that you want to iterate `allStaff.branch`

```
 {allStaff.branch.map(
  (branch,i) => {
    if(branch?.name === contributor.branch[i].name)
      return (<option key={branch._id} value={branch._id}>
        {branch.firstName}
      </option>)
   })}
```

Comment: I have modified. Please take a look

Comment: Just a note that map will produce a null value for the array if you don't return anything. While react will handle this and not display any errors, the array of jsx objects will still be the same length as the original array. This can cause issues if you use the length of the array for something or the index for numbering for example. The correct way is to run a filter first, followed by a map. Alternatively you could use your method with reduce instead.